# other alternative texthelpers in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, rubygems, helper, textile

I have text input I get from a variety of sources which is not HTML but is simple text.  I've tried using Redcloth to fit this with HTML tags to that it integrates nicely into my site, but it doesn't get bullet points or paragraphs... I checked around an found some text helpers built in, but those also didn't do the job.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html

The text looks basically like this

```
Some text

Some more text

-Maybe some point
-Another one
```

I'd like to get that with tags:

```
<p>Some text</p>
<ul>whatever</ul>
```

Other wise it just ends up looking like one long run-on paragraph.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

I installed BlueCloth and used the Markdown helper, that seemed to work ok.  Now I just have to figure out how to use it with the in_place_editor ;-(